# React: How can I show only where a boolean is set to false with Array.map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have a simple array with objects, these objects contain a boolean value.

When rendering like this, it shows every single object.

```
{props.items.map((item, index) => {
  <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>;
})}
```

The array in question:

```
items = [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "hidden": false
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "hidden": false
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "hidden": true
  },
]
```

Is it possible to only render the objects that has the "hidden" value to false?

Comment: You don't need to use `filter` before mapping. Just use `&&` like this: `props.items.map((item, index) => !item.hidden && <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use filter

```
items.filter(i => i.hidden === false);
```

Comment: or even shorter `items.filter(({ hidden }) => !hidden)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to first filter the array to get the items with `hidden: false`, the you can apply `map()` on that result array to get the HTML rendered for them.

```
{props.items.filter((item) => !item.hidden).map((item, index) => {
  <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>;
})}
```